# Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `jsx`. Zeit Styled Jsx

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, styled-jsx

I am trying to use styled-jsx with some code. However, no matter what I do, I seem to get an error

```
index.js:1437 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `jsx`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: jsx="true" or jsx={value.toString()}.
    in style (at App.js:12)
    in div (at App.js:9)
    in Test (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:29)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:27)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)
```

I have tried reinstalling node_modules, made sure my configuration is all good, and tested different versions.

My package.json,

```
{
  "name": "preview",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "contentful": "^7.4.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "styled-jsx": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-stage-2"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "styled-jsx/babel"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

My sample React code that still throws the error.

```
const Test = () => {
    return (
        <div>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <style jsx>{
            `
            p {
                color: red;
            }
            `
        }
        </style>
        </div>)
}

class App extends Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <Router>

        <Route path='/test' component={Test}/>

      </Router>

    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

I expect to not have any error messages based on the documentation

Comment: What is the `jsx` on `<style jsx>` supposed to do? That is what it is complaining about.

Comment: It's a Babel Plugin that allows me to use zeit/styled-jsx https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx

Comment: based on the error message, have you tried `<style jsx="true">`? but based on the documentation you shouldn't need to do that. How did you import the library in `App.js`?

Comment: Setting it to true removes the error message but makes it work not as expected. I don't import it, I just include it my package.json as  plugin which is how I imagine it would work. Is there some reason React wouldn't load my babel plugin?

Comment: Perhaps the Babel plugin isn't running then?

Comment: That's my theory but I'm not sure how to debug that part. I've tried making .babelrc and everything but it doesn't seem to be runninng.

Comment: @EricPoretsky I just got the same error and shared below how it's fixed in my case. Maybe you can check as well even it should be a bit late for you to use but it might be helpful for future readers.

Comment: According to the `styled jsx` `readme.md`, this is fixed with the babel plugin `styled-jsx/babel-test`. However, it didn't work for me.
https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#rendering-in-tests

Answer (score 9):

Answer to this issue is in the warning. Just convert your style's jsx attribute type from boolean to string:

from: `<style jsx> {your style here} </style>`

to: `<style jsx="true"> {your style here} </style>`

Comment: good man, please take your pluspoint

Comment: this gives me a lint error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'`

Comment: Do you use styled-jsx with CRA or NextJs? 

I forgot to mention in my answer that I didn't test it with TS. But it works fine with NextJs +  Ts

Comment: @Gnopor I'm using Next 12 + TS (plus some other stuff. basically `blitz@2.0.0-beta.19`)

Comment: @JohnVandivier I had this error when I was using CRA without TS. Now I'm using Next 12 + TS and I don't even have this issue anymore. Maybe you should try to ask a new question for your specific case.

Comment: If I do that, I lose all the CSS syntax highlighting colors. I'm using Visual Studio if that matters.

Comment: I had this error when I was using CRA without TS. Now I'm using Next 12 + TS and I don't even have this issue anymore. Maybe you should try to ask a new question for your specific case.

Answer (score 8):

OK. Since I myself spent a few hours before solving this, I hope I can help you guys who also have this problem.

To use `styled-jsx` with `create-react-app`, you need:

1. `yarn add react-app-rewired customize-cra`
2. Replace in `package.json`:

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
```

with

```
"start": "react-app-rewired start",
"build": "react-app-rewired build",
"test": "react-app-rewired test",
```

3. Create (in root directory, next to `package.json`) file `config-overrides.js`

```js
const { override, addBabelPlugin, addBabelPreset } = require('customize-cra');
module.exports = override(
    addBabelPlugin('styled-jsx/babel')
);
```

4. Create in root directory file `.babelrc` (it is only used when you run `jest test`)

```json
{
    "plugins": ["styled-jsx/babel"]
}
```

5. In your `index.js` (or where it is you mount React into DOM), before calling `ReactDOM.render(...)`, insert the following bit of code, taken from [`styled-jsx` issue #560](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx/issues/560#issuecomment-599371026)

```js
const _JSXStyle = require('styled-jsx/style').default;
if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    Object.assign(global, { _JSXStyle });
}
```

It is unfortunate, but this complex configuration is a bit fickle without it.

You need steps 4 and 5 only if you use `yarn build` or `yarn test` with create-react-app.

Comment: This is taken form here where one can found equivalent for npm https://codedaily.io/tutorials/Customize-Create-React-App-without-Ejecting

Comment: if you are using nextjs, by creating a .babelrc you opt out from the rust compiler -_-'

Answer (score 1):

Building on @gnopor 's answer.

I wrote a custom Style component for React and Typescript.

```js
interface Props {
    children: string;
    global ?: "true" | "false";
}

function Style({ children, global = "false" } : Props) {
  return (
    <style {...{ jsx : "true", global : global}}>
        {children}
    </style>
  )
}

export default Style
```

Then you can use it anywhere just like you would use the style tag with styled-jsx.

```
import Style from "../components/Style";

.
.
.

<Style>
  {`
    color: #000000
  `}
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this `<style jsx="true">*your code here*</style>`

Answer (score 0):

Even it's relatively an old question, issue still exists today and I ran into it as per screenshot;

[image]

Even it suggests to solve it via changing the line `<style jsx>` within declared **Test component** above with `<style jsx="true">`, then it's inevitable to get an error (at least warning from linter) as opposed to type safety checks incase strictly applied.

[image]

In order to easily solve this issue with JSX basics, it's spossible to replace the expression with `<style jsx={undefined}>` within provided code block as updating like below;

```
const Test = () => {
    return (
        <div>
        <p>test
        </p>
        <style jsx={undefined}>{`
            p {
                color: red;
            }
        `}
        </style>
        </div>)
}
```

**Note:** It might expected to solve it via `jsx={true}` but, in that case it still throws the same error aforementioned error above. So that this way it's neither throwing error nor lose **Styled JSX**'s features.

Answer (score -2):

Use styled-components. Nested style is not supported. Look https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx/pull/260
avoid this:

```
<div>
  <span>
      <style jsx>{...}</style>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you implement the code you link to in your question and use the link only for reference? This is the best behavior to do.