# Use styled-jsx without ejecting create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, styled-jsx

Since I started using NextJS, I've grown quite fond of styled-jsx (I know, not everyone likes it). I'd love to use it in my create react app. Locally it works great. However, react shows me the error:

```
Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `jsx`.
```

To my understanding, this means that the code does not get transpired by babel. I would need to add the babel plugin to my Create React App Babel config - which isn't possible without ejecting.

I've also read about `react-app-rewired` but I don't trust it enough to put into production. Is there a more native way to use `styled-jsx` in my create react app project?

Answer (score 3):

I just happened to answer this in details under another question :) Hope it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66285652/511908

Answer (score 2):

According to the styled-jsx docs, it can be used in `create-react-app` by using the `css.resolve` function provided in `styled-jsx/macro`. Read about it [here](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx/blob/master/readme.md#using-resolve-as-a-babel-macro).

I *think* this is the intended use but I could not get it working:

```
import css from "styled-jsx/macro";

export function Login() {
    const { demoClass, styles } = css.resolve`
        label {
            color: green;
        }
    `;

    return (
        <label className={demoClass}>Test</label>
    );
}
```

Even if this did work, I dislike it and would rather use styled components or CSS modules (built into CRA, by the way). This is nowhere near as clean as the normal styled-jsx code.

It seems that styled-jsx just does not work well with CRA without ejecting. If you do get it working please let me know, but right now I am going down the CSS modules with [Styled Components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) route.